# IAM policy that can delete snapshot on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to create an IAM policy that can delete snapshots with the Test stack tag.

I have tried my own version of the policy as such:

```
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "ec2:describe*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DeleteSnapshot"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Stack": "Test"
            }
        },
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
```

}

It doesn't work. I get permission denied when I attempt to delete snapshot as a user who is a member of a group where this policy applies.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (maybe API has been updated):

```
- Sid: RestrictSnapshotActions
  Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - ec2:DeleteSnapshot
  Resource:
    - arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*
  Condition:
    StringEquals:
       ec2:ResourceTag/Stack: Test
```

See also: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tag-amazon-ebs-snapshots-on-creation-and-implement-stronger-security-policies/

Answer (score 0):

The DeleteSnapshot API does [not support resource level permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions). So we cannot use any conditions except "ec2:Region" and AWS global conditions.

So, you have to remove the condition block to be able to delete the snapshot.